# Log4j2 change logger level at runtime (tomcat and jboss)

Tags: log4j2

I read that among the new features of log4j2 is possible to set the property "monitorInterval." How you can use this feature to load at runtime the log level? (For example how to change from DEBUG to WARN?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What this feature does is re-initialize the configuration (read from the config file). If you modify the config file, log4j will pick up the change.